# How to install Microsoft Reportviewer exe in web apps service hosted in azure?

Tags: azure, rdlc, azure-web-app-service, report-viewer2010, azure-webapps

In my application we have referred below two dlls:

1. Microsoft.ReportViewer.Common.dll
2. Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms.dll

with the ReportViewer version 2010

But after deploying to azure web apps I am getting exception that the .rdlc file is invalid where as it works in local dev environment. In local environment I have installed the reportviewer installer.

Below is the exception:

**An error occurred during local report processing.
The definition of the report 'Reports\Report1.rdlc' is invalid.**

Is it possible to access the system drives and install reportviewer.exe in web apps?

Or please suggest me a way so that the rdlc files can be generated

Comment: How about this? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/sqlclassic/virtual-machines-windows-classic-sql-server-reportviewer

Comment: I tried the same but no luck. I found from the kudu site that the ReportViewer folder is missing from Programe Files(86).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the resolution:

1. Add Microsoft.ReportViewer.ProcessingObjectModel.dll in project reference along with Microsoft.ReportViewer.Common.dll and Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms.dll
2. Make sure Microsoft.ReportViewer.ProcessingObjectModel.dll, Microsoft.ReportViewer.Common.dll and Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms.dll are present in bin folder in deployed environment.

***Note:*** Make sure all the dlls are of same version.